# Bash script runs faster from file than in command line

Tags: bash, command-line

If I put this bash script

```
for ((i=0; i < 111; i++)); do
    echo $i
done
```

in a file and run it, it runs faster than if I typed it directly in the command line. Why is this? (I'm running Ubuntu.)

Comment: Define "faster". You only have 111 items in your loop so I'm sure both execute in less than half a second...

Comment: Additional, for a bigger list, this kind of loop will spend most of the time waiting for the terminal to print the output.

Comment: Have you checked the execution time for both ? If not , how can you tell one is faster than the other .

Comment: how did you messure the time

Comment: I was just looking at the output. The inline script seemed to print much more slowly than the file. Using time confirms this: I got 
    real 0m4.918s
    user 0m0.312s
    sys  0m0.540s
for inline and
    real 0m0.034s
    user 0m0.016s
    sys  0m0.004s
for file.

Answer (score 1):

I executed these two examples and checked execution time using `time`.

Running in file:

```
real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Running from command line:

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Only thing I can think of that would cause this difference would be that when you execute a script / file you also need to account for the disk access and whatever filesystem you are running on.

Comment: Your machine does the opposite of mine: inline is faster than file. I thought this might have been a general issue.